# Creating a new string based on the name of a dictionary key

Tags: python, arrays

If I had a dictionary like below

```
mydict = {'Key1': 'test', 'Key2': 'test', 'Key3': 'test',}
```

And I wanted to, based on the dictionary key names (not the values), create new strings named after them. How do I do this. i.e I need 3 strings named Key1, Key2, Key3.

Just can't seem to work it out. And if this was in a loop, how would I assign values to those new strings.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Most of the time it's completely unnecessary to dynamically create variable names, and it's bad practice.

Comment: If you want to assign values to strings, why not just do `mydict["Key1"] = put_value_here`?

Answer (score 1):

`mydict.keys()` will return a list of strings of the keys. You can then use that whichever way you want.

```
In [4]:mydict.keys()
Out[4]:['Key3', 'Key2', 'Key1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)

```
mydict = {'Key1': 'test', 'Key2': 'test', 'Key3': 'test',}
for k in d.keys():
    vars()[k] = mydict[k]

print Key1 # -> test
```

Comment: Note that using `vars()` without an argument is the same as `locals()` which states: *The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter*